# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, bluebird

I deleted the local folder which contained `bluebird` on my system using:

`rm -rf <module_path>`

And now when I try to install it again using:

`npm install bluebird` or `npm install bluebird --save` I get the following error everytime:

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'bluebird'
```

I'm kind of stuck here because the only way I can think of fixing the error is by installing bluebird but I can't install it because of the above error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was because of an issue with my `package-lock.json`. I deleted the `package-lock` and reran `npm install` and that ended up fixing my issue

Answer (score -1):

This issue occurred with me a couple of times then i reached the solution:

You need to clear the npm cache first

```
npm clear cache -f
```

Then I removed the package-lock-json file

Also, remove the node_modules

Then `npm install` .

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` instead